# How do I colorize an image in Mapbox SymbolLayer?

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using Mapbox to render some Point GeoJSON data. How do I colorize an icon using SymbolLayer on Android? This seems to be causing a lot of trouble to others as well. This question is exactly mine: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/1594

```
    val symbolLayer = SymbolLayer("clientLocationsPointsLayer", "clientLocationsPointsSource")
    symbolLayer.setProperties(
        iconImage("square"),
        iconSize(get("radius")),
        iconAllowOverlap(true),
        iconColor(get("color")),
        iconOpacity(get("opacity"))
    )
```

My `square` image is a png. The docs say it needs to be an SDF. How do I make one of those? Is there another way to do this? On iOS this was much simpler. Does Android really not have a good equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue in the future, here in the mapbox examples is the answer.
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/property-icon-determination/

You can create multiple icons using Android-Studio built-in Vector asset creator. Right click on Drawables->New->Vector Asset->Clip art. Here you can find the icon you like and set color directly in this editor.

After that, use mapbox expressions to get color value and set your image based on the color.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.